# Swift UIApplication not in scope

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiapplication

I want to change isIdleTimerDisabled when a specific view appears. In SwiftUI I use

```swift
.onAppear { 
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true 
}
.onDisappear { 
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false 
}
```

but even with `import UIKit` I get the warning

> Cannot find 'UIApplication' in scope

How can I fix that? I didn't find a solution after searching for more than an hour.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not need to import `UIKit`, it should work with `SwiftUI`.

The problem may be your target. Is the file used only on an iOS or iPadOS application target?

Or is it also used, for instance, in an extension, like ShareExtension, and so on?

If it is, you cannot access `UIApplication` within your code. If this code is shared between extensions and app, you should use conditional compilation to avoid this problem.

Comment: Oh yes, the file has a WatchKit Extension. "#if os(iOS)" solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Lars so how did you use '#if os(iOS)'

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651876